# Let $P$ be the set of all permutations in $S_{6}$ that can be expressed as a product of a multiple of $4$ transposition then $|P|$ is....$?$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $P$ be the set of all permutations in $S_{6}$ that can be expressed as a product of a multiple of $4$ transposition then $|P|$ is...$?$

I counted all the permutations of $S_{6}$, that are product of $4$ disjoint cycles. These are $85$

But answer is given $360$. Maybe I'm not clearly getting, what the question is asking.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell without you explaining how you got to the number of $85$. The right answer seems to be $360=6!/2$, because all those permutations are even, and you can get every even permutation of $6$ elements as a composition of four transpositions. (Use them to get the first four elements in the permutation right, the last two will be uniquely determined because only one ordering of them corresponds to the entire permutation being even - the other transposes them making the entire permutation odd.)

Comment: @Srinking Bishop, I just counted those permutation, whose cycle decomposition contain $4$ disjoint cycles.

Comment: But the question doesn't say anything about disjoint cycles, does it? That's something you made up? I believe it's asking for permutations that can be expressed in the form $\tau_1\tau_2\tau_3\tau_4$ where the $\tau_i$ are transpositions, that is, $2$-cycles. Like for instance $$(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)(5\ 6)=(1\ 2)(2\ 3)(3\ 4)(5\ 6)$$

Comment: The question says a product of a  multiple of four transpositions, not exactly four transpositions. (Although as it happens all elements of $A_6$ do arise as a product of four transpositions. Not that to prove that you only need to prove it for each cycle type.)

Comment: @DerekHolt I thought the OP misstated the problem, or mistranslated it from a foreign language. I can't imagine what "a product of a multiple of four transpositions" could even mean. Well, I never studied group theory, and I believe you are an expert, so could you kindly explain it to me. In a group, isn't everything a multiple of everything else? So wouldn't the answer then be $720$ instead of $360$? And what's the difference between "a multiple of four transpositions" and "a product of a multiple of four transpositions"? Isn't the product of one thing (a multiple) just that thing?

Comment: @Mathsaddict Now I guess you can see where you made the mistake (looking for disjoint cycles rather than just composing transpositions). Please check if you can now solve the problem, and if not, feel free to ask further questions. One thing is, however, worrying me: in $S_6$ you have $6$ elements to permute *altogether* - how did you manage to make even *a single* decomposition of a permutation into four disjoint cycles (let alone $85$ such decompositions)? (You would need at least $8$ elements for that.)

Comment: @bof I interpreted "a product of a multiple of four transpositions" to mean the set of all elements $g$ of $S_6$ that can be expressed as  $g = g_1g_2 \cdots g_k$, where each $g_i$ is a transposition in $S_6$, and $k$ is a multiple of $4$. The fact that $k$ is even implies that all such $g \in G$ must lie in $A_6$.

Comment: Wow, it never occurred to me that "a multiple of four transpositions" could be parsed that way. Thanks!